# NSMutableArray: what does object at index do exactly?

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I am running the following code and CCLOG always get triggered.. the two pointers have the same address and I don't understand why.. I need help :)

bullets is a NSMutable array with 200 hundred instances of Bullet:CCSprite initialized as at the end of this question*.

```
for (int i=0; i<capacity; i++)
{
    Bullet* bullet = [bullets objectAtIndex:i];

    if (bullet.visible )
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<capacity;j++)
        {

            Bullet * otherBullet = bullet = [bullets objectAtIndex:j];

            if(bullet.bulletId == otherBullet.bulletId)
            {
                CCLOG(@"noooo.. i:%i j_%j", i, j);
            }
```

*Initialization of array:

```
capacity=200;
    bullets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:capacity];
    // Create a number of bullets up front and re-use them whenever necessary.
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
    {
        Bullet* bullet = [Bullet bulletWithScreenRect:screenRect];
        bullet.visible = NO;
        bullet.bulletId=i;
        [bullets addObject:bullet];
        [self addChild:bullet];
```

Comment: `Bullet * otherBullet = bullet = ...` -- of course they have the same value.

Comment: Well spotted. I've been staring at this :P

Comment: All I found was a curious `%j`

Comment: @kevingessner what a stupid mistake have I done. Thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in my code spotted by kevingessner:

"            Bullet * otherBullet = bullet = [bullets objectAtIndex:j];"

was assigning the latest bullet to bullet as well as to otherBullet having in this way two pointers to the same bullet.

..so "object at index" just does it jobs (return a pointer to an object at a specific index)